# Check password in Linq-to-SQL using BCrypt

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, bcrypt

I using BCrypt to hash passwords. 
In my login query I check passwords:

> var kier = (from b in baza.Logowanies where b.Login ==
>   model.Użytkownik && **BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(model.Hasło,
>   b.Haslo)** && b.konto == "kierownik" select b).Any();

During compilation I have a error:

> Method 'Boolean CheckPassword(System.String, System.String)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Linq-to-SQL which means your Linq query is being translated into SQL statements that are run against the database. There is no CheckPassword in SQL. You will first have to load the user from the database without the password hash check. Then do your hash checking. Something like:

```
var user = (from b in baza.Logowanies where b.Login == model.Użytkownik && b.konto == "kierownik" select b).FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null && BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(model.Hasło, user.Haslo))
{
    // Do login.
}
else
{
    // Fail login.
}
```

Note that there's a language barrier here and I might've made some wrong guesses.